# Why is there an "A" in the software centre icon?

Tags: software-center, icons, design

The stock Software Centre icon certainly contains an "A", but why exactly? "Ubuntu" does not contain an A, and I can not imagine it is for "c**A**nonic**A**l" or "softw**A**re".

[image: Software centre]

It makes sense for companies like "**A**pp*e" to have an A there, and they already have, but why not a "U" or something instead?

I realize it is just a combination of a loading bar and an up-arrow, but for me it looks like the letter "A".

What is the reason behind this design choice?

Comment: **A**pps, I guess?

Comment: Maybe it's for "**A**pplications" ?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/raring-updates-software-center-icon

Comment: @JonasCz I think you **A**re **A**bsolutely right. This is **A** little bit emb**A**rr**A**ssing...